# codeigniter site works on local machine. Does not work if I test it in a different device on same network. Any ideas?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, device

I have been developing websites for a while but this is the most bizzare situation I have came across.

I have a codeigniter project that works well on MAMP on my macbook. However, if I try and test it on other devices (other notebook computers, tablets) on the same device then it opens up without loading css.

Any ideas.. why this would be a problem. I doubt that it is because of .htaccess. If so, could someone please guide me on how to fix this.

Thanks Heaps!

Comment: either open page in firefox (with firebug installed) or fire up chrome browser and use "inspect element" feature, in bottom right hand corner there is a "error count" click on it and it takes you straight to `html/javaScript` error, debug further from that point.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's an incorrect path to the file. Check your browser's development tools to see if there's a 404 error for that file.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your `$config['base_url'] = '';` right.

It should be `$config['base_url'] = 'http://<servers device IP>/project';`

What is happening is that if you set it to `http://localhost/project`, all CSS/JavaScript is loaded from "localhost" (your device [tablet, phone], not the "server device") and throws 404 for desired request, HTML is still rendered but without any styles/JavaScript.

I doubt you've installed php server on your tablet ;)